# No se aplica el cambio de orden en vista xs en las columnas de Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap, bootstrap-4

tengo el siguiente problema con Bootstrap. Estoy intentando cambiar el orden en que se muestran 2 divs en la vista xs

EL caso es que si pongo order-1 en la segunda columna, y order-2 en la primera si me cambia el orden, pero al aplicarle en la vista que quiero que se muestren esta no cambia.

El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    <div class="order-xs-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
        <div class="menu">
            <p class="titulo-cat">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae amet a beatae quod atque quia quaerat numquam ea pariatur architecto, fugiat repudiandae, nesciunt adipisci saepe maiores sequi, aut est cupiditate.</p>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="menu menu-2">
            <p class="titulo-cat">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur cupiditate, aliquam. Laboriosam eius a vero cum dolores optio inventore cupiditate possimus porro sunt. Ad ducimus sint minus accusantium sunt, fuga.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-xs-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 cont-productos ">
        <div class="row cont">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam facilis sed dolorem sint similique expedita distinctio et illum, magni maiores, non dolorum, debitis doloribus. Repudiandae vitae quaerat reiciendis consequuntur, nobis!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

¿ Qué estoy haciendo mal ?

Answer (score 0):

`.order-xs-*` no existe, es `.order-*` para `xs` (como con casi todas las clases de Bootstrap). [Documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/flex/#order).

Tenés que pensar en *mobile first*. Tu HTML armalo pensando primero en `xs`, las clases usalas para modificar como se ve en el resto de los cortes.

```
<div>
    <div class="order-sm-2 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-9 col-xl-9 cont-productos ">
        <div class="row cont">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ipsam facilis sed dolorem sint similique expedita distinctio et illum, magni maiores, non dolorum, debitis doloribus. Repudiandae vitae quaerat reiciendis consequuntur, nobis!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-sm-1 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
        <div class="menu">
            <p class="titulo-cat">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quae amet a beatae quod atque quia quaerat numquam ea pariatur architecto, fugiat repudiandae, nesciunt adipisci saepe maiores sequi, aut est cupiditate.</p>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="menu menu-2">
            <p class="titulo-cat">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur cupiditate, aliquam. Laboriosam eius a vero cum dolores optio inventore cupiditate possimus porro sunt. Ad ducimus sint minus accusantium sunt, fuga.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si uso order-* solo me cambia el orden en todas las vistas, y solo quiero que la cambie en XS, he probado con order-sm-* según la documentación pero no cabia nada

Comment: Fijate que lo que hice fue invertir el HTML para que por defecto lo veas como querés en `XS` y después use la clase `order-sm-*` para cambiar el orden de `sm` en adelante.